# iframe with height 0 using iframe-resizer plugin

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I've a page with some iframe, I've used the iframe-resizer plugin to autoresize the iframes, but it has a very strange behavior:
At the beginning just one iframe is visible, the others are all display: none.
Sometimes when i switch from one iframe to another, the new iframe appaer to have height 0 on firefox and height 4398px(too high) on chrome, the common behavior is that, resizing the browser, the iframe get the right height.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you are currently using? It sounds to me like you are only init-ing the plugin on the first iframe element, so I'd love to see your selector.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in FireFox. You can work around it by using `visibility: hidden`, instead of `display: none`.